# Elasticsearch java top level query

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I am trying to run a search on the following json using the java api

```
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "query" : {
        "filtered": {
          "query": { "match_all": {}},
          "filter" : {
            "and": {"filters":[
              {"term": {"term": "value"}}
            ]}
          }
        }
      },
      "child_type": "child"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the java code I have,

```
        QueryBuilders.hasChildQuery("child", QueryBuilders
                           .filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(),
                                         FilterBuilders.andFilter(FilterBuilders.
                                          termFilter("term", "value"))));
```

However this just produces the json

```
{"has_child":
    {"query":
        {"filtered":
            {"query":{"match_all":{}},
                "filter":{
                "and":
                    {"filters":[
                        {"term":{"term":"value"}}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "child_type":"child"
    }
}
```

As you can see I am missing a top level `{ "query" : ... }` but I cannot find out how to add this top level query using the java api for elasticsearch.

Comment: I'm having the same problem if I try to wrap it with boolQuery, my top level ends up being `{"bool" : ...}`

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding inside the code

```
client.prepareSearch("parent-child")
            .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
            .setQuery(query)
            .setFrom(0).setSize(60).setExplain(true)
            .execute()
            .actionGet();
```

It autowraps the query with `{"query" : ...}`

My issue was that I was searching on the wrong index.